# What are the main different/alternative correlation estimators?

Tags: correlation, spearman-rho, pearson-r, estimators

**I'm looking to learn about the main/popular alternatives when it comes to estimating correlations that I've missed in the following list**. The best answer will provide a reference (can be Wikipedia), a quick description and a motivation/purpose/reason to use.

Here's the ones that I'm already aware of:

---

$$\text{Unconditional estimators}$$

- [Pearson estimate.](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDcQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient&ei=9PPKUOyiCsaQiQeM-oDwAg&usg=AFQjCNG-VIeZ9v8IAK-77pfjEKMYBrw5AA&sig2=ujAAiDQvHzUhUQiE7_rqQQ&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.aGc)
- [Kendall tau estimate.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_tau_rank_correlation_coefficient)
- [Spearman's rank correlation estimate](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%2527s_rank_correlation_coefficient&ei=IvTKUJ6rOqywiQf8sYEw&usg=AFQjCNGG7VyKUBSAQMZLOG9qlkAld40y3Q&sig2=LwdJJ2Xl31kQPHfFkgUa8g&bvm=bv.1355325884,d.aGc)

$$\text{Time-varying estimators}$$

- [DCC](http://www.cass.city.ac.uk/__data/assets/pdf_file/0003/78843/Engle2028200229.pdf)-fGARCH time-varying correlation estimate. (i.e., DCC(p,q) with different GARCH variants; common ones in finance are GARCH, eGARCH, TGARCH or GJR-GARCH).
- Time-varying correlations by Kalman Filter regressions (however I'm ignorant of this methodology, I've just seen it in a paper that I glanced through).

$$\text{Estimators for distributional extremes}$$

- The new technology on the block; [quantile correlations](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2153697), a purportedly robust way of estimating the correlations at the extremes/tails of one of the variables.

---

I know that some correlation work has been done with random matrices but I'm ignorant of this.

Comment: It's not really possible to list *all* correlation estimates. There's potentially an infinity of infinities of them.

Comment: Do you care about the measures of association in contingency tables?